# catkin work space initializing

Tags: ros, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS version Lunar on ubuntu 16.04 . I was trying to initializing the catkin work space that this error appeared :

```
Could neither symlink nor copy file "/opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake" to "/opt/ros/lunar/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt":
- [Errno 13] Permission denied
- [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/ros/lunar/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt'negar
```

what should I do???

I prefer not to reinstall it and when I use sudo, It's not work

I also create directory in $HOME , but :

negar@negar:/home/ros_working/catkin_ws/src$ catkin_init_workspace
Could neither symlink nor copy file "/opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake" to "/home/ros_working/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt":

- [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ros_working/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt'

And when I use sudo :  sudo: catkin_init_workspace: command not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276766/catkin-work-space-initializing/) by [NegarL](https://answers.ros.org/users/32775/negarl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> what should I do???

not try to make your Catkin workspace in a non-world-writable location. `/opt/ros/lunar/catkin_ws` is a location only writable by `root` (or users with similar permissions).

Try to create your workspace in your $HOME directory.

---

Edit: please add how you created your workspace (ie: the `/home/ros_working/catkin_ws` directory).

Also include the output of `ls -al /home/ros_working/catkin_ws` in your update.

> And when I use sudo , sudo: catkin_init_workspace: command not found

**never** use `sudo` with ROS. It is hardly ever really necessary, and there are almost always other ways to achieve what you want to do.

It's certainly not needed to be able to create, init and build a workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NegarL](https://answers.ros.org/users/32775/negarl/) on 2017-11-27**:
Thanks but It's ok to do that ?? to build it in another directory ?? no problem will occur ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:
I would say it's best practice to *not* build in `/opt/ros/..`.

**Comment by [NegarL](https://answers.ros.org/users/32775/negarl/) on 2017-11-27**:
I made my catkin work space in $HOME but I still have the problem !

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:\

> I made my catkin work space in $HOME but I still have the problem !

then please tell us *exactly* which commands you used.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:
Don't use comments for this kind of update, **edit** your original question to add new info.

**Comment by [NegarL](https://answers.ros.org/users/32775/negarl/) on 2017-11-28**:
thanks, It was fixed

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-28**:
You did not include the output of `ls -al /home/ros_working/catkin_ws` in your update.